# Find the value of c to make f XY (x,y)=c(2x+y) a valid joint pdf

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Find the value of  c to make  f(x,y)=c(2x+y) a valid joint pdf
There is no limits, so would I take the double integral from -infinity to infinity...I'm so confused how this would make it a conclusive answer.

Comment: No, indeed, there will need to be finite bounds for that to be a valid probability density function.

Comment: It must be a mistake, has to have limits for such pdf.

Comment: I thought of such...thank you!